# How to add_filter to a class function within a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, add-filter

I want to change the output of a permalink that is returned from the plugin function `getPermalink()`.

Here is the plugin file (removed unnecessary lines):

```
<?php

namespace DgoraWcas;

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
class Product
{
    /**
     * Get product permalink
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPermalink()
    {
        $permalink = $this->wcProduct->get_permalink();
        return apply_filters(
            'dgwt/wcas/product/permalink',
            $permalink,
            $this->productID,
            $this
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried adding this to my functions file:

```
add_filter( 'dgwt/wcas/product/permalink', array( __CLASS__, 'testFunction') );
function testFunction() {
    return "test";
}
```

Just for trial, I was hoping this would return the link as: 'test'.

When I add this the plugin doesn't load content correctly. Am I missing something that happens?

Comment: _"I've tried adding this to my functions file"_ - so `testFunction` is just a stand-alone function, and not a class method? Then `array( __CLASS__, 'testFunction')` makes no sense, it would have to be just `'testFunction'` then.

Comment: Aside from what CBroe said, please define what "doesn't load content correctly" means. Kinda confused, not sure if you mean to say that the link isn't using 'test' as its `href` value or whether something else happened.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for pointing this out. As you can tell I'm not too experienced, I thought I had to specify the class where I wanted to add the function. Thanks for the help guys!